# AttributeError: module 'keras' has no attribute '__version__'

Tags: python, keras, anaconda

```
import keras
keras.__version__
```

When I'm working in a .ipynb notebook in VSCode, I'm importing Keras. Then, to confirm Keras is loaded properly, I'm asking what version of Keras is "running". It gives the following error.

```
AttributeError: module 'keras' has no attribute '__version__'
```

I'm using Anaconda latest build with base-env. I'm on macOS.

Comment: The fact that you are getting the error for `__version__` means that there was no problem in importing `keras`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.version.VERSION)
```

Comment: I havent installed tensorflow yet, but keras separately. However... I want to install the tensorflow DL-package via Anaconda Navigator. It remains on "solving package specifications" status.

Is installing via ` conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow ` doing the same thing or is it different from installing via Navigator GUI?

I have already installed `keras` and `keras.preprocessing` via Navigator. Is this becaue of keras being installed separately?

Comment: Check this thread [here](https://groups.google.com/g/keras-users/c/73s4KZJUsqA?pli=1), it contains similar explanation as well. Someone here has obtained the version using `keras.__version__`, and so I think it has something to do with 
1) Either the version of your keras module
2) The fact that you are directly using `import keras` over `import tensorflow.keras as keras`

Answer (score 1):

Keras moved from being a library of TF (so import TF and you get Keras) to being a library that works with TF (and JAX, and PyTorch) as backend (so you import both Keras and TF).

To print the Keras version, since Tensorflow version 2.13 you should simply use

```
import keras

print(keras.__version__)
```

Source of information: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/62398